# Symlink to /sys/bus/spi/devices

Tags: symlink, devices, sysfs

I'm trying to port a certain software from one linux device to another. My software has a lot of lines pointing to **/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi3.0**. In the Linux device I'm porting to, that folder does not exist, it's in another place.

Is there a way to symlink so that the software goes to, say for e.g. "**/tmp/folder**" instead?

I've been trying to use **"ln -s"** but I get complaints that the folder "/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi3.0" does not exist. I know there are solutions for this if the device really exists but in my case "**/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi3.0**" does not exist on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a symbolic link, it has to be named `/spi/devices/spi3.0`. If it isn't, nothing will work. So you need:

```
mkdir -p /spi/devices
ln -s /yournewlocation /spi/device/spi3.0
```

If you don't have access to do that, a symbolic link isn't going to help.

Comment: So there's no way of making a folder there? I don't seem to be able, not even with root access. I'm thinking maybe I should do some virtual/dummy SPI interface with the name spi3.0 and then make a symlink or pipe everything from there to the true interface file.

Comment: If you have root access, use those two commands above. The first makes sure you have all the parent folders. The second one makes a symbolic link called `/spi/device/spi3.0` which will point at `/yournewlocation` (obviously, /yournewlocation will be `/tmp/folder` or whatever). Then you should be able to do `cd /spi/device/spi3.0`, and also your program should work OK.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it's not working. I think it may be because i'm working with the /sys directory which is part of sysfs (virtual file system). I'm thinking that maybe i should mount a virtual driver there to pose as a fake spi.